# how to find the "Natural and Total Response" of the system

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, homework

Hello there I am a Student.

I need to know how to find the Natural and Total Response of the given system:

[image]

[image]
where: $x(t)=e^{-t}u(t)$ and $y(0^+)=2, \dfrac{d}{dt}y(0^+)=3$. (If the image above is not clear)

This is for my exam preparation, please kindly help or at least specify where
I can find the solution for this question, and  best tutorial for signal and system.

Comment: Thank you sir, am wondering how yourself rewrite the equation, kindly acknowledge me.., and what about my question kindly provide the best suggestions...

Comment: Do you know what is meant by "natural response" and "total response"? Do you know the Laplace transform? What have you tried so far? By the way, the constant factors on the left-hand side of the top equation are illegible (at least for me).

Comment: am Btec-IT student in kerala,**India**. I have this subject called **Signals and Systems** and **Digi_Sig_Procssing**, i know these kinds of question but it is from Exam Qestion Paper an Applied Level or Some thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I'll assume you do do what a Laplace transform really is!

All you have to do, is just compute the la place inverse for each part to get the result you want.
If you want the natural response only, just find the inverse Laplace transform of the noted part. If you want the total response just take the inverse Laplace transform for the whole factor.

Comment: oh thank you man, i wonder such people exists, man can you suggest good **exam oriented question and answer** books or any web sites....' +1 and  tick ' to this fast response..

Comment: I've studies from "Linear Systems and Signals" by LATHI second edition.
There are alot of good examples, and problems which can really help you understanding what's going on!
Best of luck!
@akcHitman